# How I can update nested relationships

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm learn DRF, trying write simple monitoring system for computers.
With client I havent problem, but with server have one - UPDATE foreign key.

Code - https://pastebin.com/HgKXKNh0

How I can known pk for Disk and NetAdapter in

```
        for disk_data in disks_data:
            Disks.objects.update(client=instance, **disk_data)
 
        for adapter_data in net_adapter_data:
            NetAdapter.objects.update(client=instance, **adapter_data)
```

**def create(self, validated_data)** from https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers, I tried to do the same update, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change some logic in `update` method.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    disks_data = validated_data.pop('disk')
    net_adapter_data = validated_data.pop('adapter')
    
    for attr, value in validated_data.items():
        setattr(instance, attr, value)

    for disk_data in disks_data:
        if 'id' in disk_data.keys():
            disk_id = disk_data.pop('id')
            Disks.objects.filter(id = disk_id).update(client = instance, **disk_data)
        else:
            Disks.objects.create(client = instance, **disk_data)

    for adapter_data in net_adapter_data:
        if 'id' in adapter_data.keys():
            adapter_id = adapter_data.pop('id')
            NetAdapter.objects.filter(id = adapter_id).update(client = instance, **adapter_data)
        else:
            NetAdapter.objects.create(client=instance, **adapter_data)

    return instance
```

Hope it could help.

Comment: Very thanks, but no. Client nothing know about id disk and adapter. Every query adding new object. :(

Comment: the clients don't know about id but the frontend should know about the id because it receives JSON data from server.

Comment: how to detect the Disk or NetAdapter data is old one or new one? Could you tell me about that in detail? Are there any fields to use to detect them?